# how to add parameters in a javascript object (DataTables)?

Tags: javascript, datatables, tabletools

I want to build a DataTable with the following parameters.

```
var table3 = $('#msg').dataTable({
    "scrollY":          calcDataTableHeight(),
    "scrollCollapse":   true,
    "paging":           false,
    "bInfo":            false,
    "order":            [[0, "desc"]],
    "dom": "Tfrtip",
    "ajax": {
        "url": "includes/DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/Editor-1.3.3/php/table.msg.php",
        "data": function (d){
            d.cat = cat;
        },
        "type": "POST"
    }
});
```

Some Parameters depend on Variables. So if needed I want to add these to the object.

```
if (buttons == true) {
add this to table 3
        "tableTools": {
        "sRowSelect": "os",
        "aButtons": [
            { "sExtends": "editor_create", "editor": editor },
            { "sExtends": "editor_edit",   "editor": editor },
            { "sExtends": "editor_remove", "editor": editor }
        ]
    }
```

How can I do this? I tried a lot, but nothing works.

Comment: table3.tableTools = {...}

Comment: That can be achieved easily with a facade pattern and a closure. I encourage you to learn more about JavaScript to write scalable and extensible code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your options as an object and then pass it to DataTables after you're done.

For example:

```
 var options = {
    "scrollY":          calcDataTableHeight(),
    "scrollCollapse":   true,
    "paging":           false,
    "bInfo":            false,
    "order":            [[0, "desc"]],
    "dom": "Tfrtip",
    "ajax": {
        "url": "includes/DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/Editor-1.3.3/php/table.msg.php",
        "data": function (d){
            d.cat = cat;
        },
        "type": "POST"
    }
};

if (buttons == true) {
   options['tableTools'] = {
      "sRowSelect": "os",
      "aButtons": [
         { "sExtends": "editor_create", "editor": editor },
         { "sExtends": "editor_edit",   "editor": editor }
      ]
   };

   if (showRemoveBtn) {
      options['tableTools']['aButtons'].push(
         { "sExtends": "editor_remove", "editor": editor }
      );
   }
}

var table3 = $('#msg').dataTable(options);
```

It could also be done with [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), if you want.

Comment: one more thing. how can I append a parameter on demand? So that the the two lines create and edit are fixed and remove depends on the if?

Answer (score 0):

If you need initialize the plugin with different parameters, you can build a facade function that handles that for you, by extending the options:

```
var showDataTable = (function($) {

    var _defaults = {
        "scrollY":        calcDataTableHeight(),
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false,
        "bInfo":          false,
        "order":          [[0, "desc"]],
        "dom":            "Tfrtip",
        "ajax": {
            "url": "includes/DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/Editor-1.3.3/php/table.msg.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function (data) {
                //do something with data
            }
        }
    };

    function calcDataTableHeight() {
        //implementation
    }

    // Initializes "dataTable" plugin
    function showDataTable (selector, options) {
        if (!selector) return;
        var config = $.extend(true, {}, _defaults, options);
        return $(selector).dataTable(config);
    }

    return showDataTable;
}(jQuery));
```

You can use it as follow:

```
if (buttons) {
    //initializes by extending options
    showDataTable("#msg", {
        "tableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "os",
            "aButtons": [
                { "sExtends": "editor_create", "editor": editor },
                { "sExtends": "editor_edit",   "editor": editor },
                { "sExtends": "editor_remove", "editor": editor }
            ]
        }
    });
} else {
    //initializes with default options
    showDataTable("#msg");
}
```